# Graduated but still working on bachelor's project, how to write in CV

Tags: thesis, cv, research-undergraduate

I graduated my bachelor's recently (have not received the final degree yet, but all the requirements are done and I have a provisional degree). As part of the degree, we are required to do a bachelor's project during the last two semesters. We also have to do courses in parallel, so nobody really expects this bachelor's project to contain work equivalent to a full-blown thesis.

Now, since I still had a few months till I start with my master's, I thought of continuing with the work that I did for my bachelor's project (also partly because I had not been able to fully achieve what I had planned; various reasons but mostly due to lack of time and guidance required for an area in which very less prior work has been done).

I have done a significant amount of work in these few months and want to mention it in my CV. I had written something like this earlier:

```
Bachelor's Thesis                                    August 2019 - present
<my institution>                                     <my supervisor>
```

But this will clearly not work now/ will create confusions.

How should I modify it to convey that I am still working on it and a part of what I did was for my bachelor's project?

Answer (score 2):

```
Bachelor's Thesis                           August 2019 - formal end date
<my institution>                            <my supervisor> 

Blah blah blah. I have since built upon my thesis to...
```

Comment: Do you think keeping the title as "Bachelor's Thesis" would be appropriate even if I end up doing more work after being graduated?

Comment: @Abhirikshma I think the above makes it absolutely clear that you extended your thesis after. Perhaps extended is the wrong word though, because your thesis hasn't changed, it has been submitted and graded. _Built-upon_ is better, I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

You should be a bit more specific. Instead of just "Bachelor's Thesis" give it a name - or a name for the project, along with the detail that it was for the thesis.

Then in a "Work in Progress" section list the project again, by name, and note that it is an extension of the thesis.

Generally speaking it is good to show a *Work in Progress* section as it indicates you haven't been idle.

Comment: This is a good idea but I don't have a "Work in Progress" section in my CV, I just list an ongoing project under "Experiences" and write "XY - present" in the duration.